# Python Gmail Error

Tags: python, gmail

```
from apiclient import errors


ImportError: cannot import name 'errors'
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled all of my google apis and still throws the same error

Comment: What is `apiclient`? Is this your own module? Is `apiclient` the Google API module you are using? Please provide more details here.

Comment: I am using other scripts from stack overflow and google developer API to call all of my gmail data. The apiclient is referring to Google API Module. I have pip installed and uninstalled apiclient and google-api-python-client

Comment: I'm putting my money on you creating a python file called `apiclient.py` and that is clashing with the Google module name `apiclient.py`. Because I just pip installed the Google API client, and your line of code works fine for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417807/google-api-python-client-doesnt-work-and-makes-spyder-to-fail-when-starting                                               I am assuming it has to deal with my permission at work

Comment: Are you saying that is what you got when you tried to pip install? And then you tried to use the module after getting an error in your pip install command?

Comment: when I pip installed the "Requirements are already satisfied", but when I run my command Spyder cannot find  the apiclient 'Errors'

Comment: Please put together a better [mcve]. It's hard to determine what your problem really is right now. Edit your question to include more information.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I went to my System administrator and I am not allowed to run APIs with my current setup, for anyone else who might run into this in an organization, it would seem that Administrator privileges are required to run APIs